# Visual Studio 2010 c++ compiler issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have the following very strange situation... my Visual Studio compiler 2010 does not like the following piece of code:

```
    QStringList lst2 = instantiatedTableInstances.split(strComma, skipper);

    for(int i=0; i<lst2.size(); i++)
    {
        TableInstance* tabInst= v->getTableInstance(lst2.at(i));
        result->addInstantiatedTableInstance(tabInst);
    }
```

it gives me:

```
..\src\DeserializationFactory.cpp(1196) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
..\src\DeserializationFactory.cpp(1196) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'QStringList' to 'int'
    No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
..\src\DeserializationFactory.cpp(1198) : error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
   type is 'int'
..\src\DeserializationFactory.cpp(1200) : error C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
    type is 'int'
```

and a screenshot:

[image: VS2010 error]

**BUT** if I rename the variable to `lst` instead of `lst2` everything compiles...

Is this a funny bug in Visual Studio 2010 (because GCC does not care about it) or there is a more hidden reason for this?

Comment: Check that lst2 is not already defined/declared/macro in the scope.

Comment: lst2 is a macro. From the screenshot it looks like it has different color, that should give it away

Comment: Tip: Fixed by defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These kind of errors are usually the result of an unexpected macro with the same name of your variable. A bit of google will find you this line in the Windows SDK header `Dlgs.h`:

```
#define lst2        0x0461
```

That's what I call *name pollution*!

My guess is that MS people thought that using a different ID for the controls of each dialog what hard to maintain, and so they though of giving the lists of *any* dialog the same IDs: `lst1`, `lst2`, `lst3` ... `lst16`. And the same with any other type of control. But for some reason the idea didn't catch and the `Dlgs.h` header was forgotten.

Now, the weird thing is that this header is included by default in your VC++ project and not in your GCC compilation. Maybe the environment is not the same.

Comment: You beat me to it; have a +1. *Prime example* of what's wrong with macros.

Comment: @Angew: Everybody knows that macros are evil. But if it where named `WIN32_DLG_DEFAULT_LIST_2` nobody would care. Using `lst2` as a macro name is evil and stupid.

Comment: The preprocessor defines in `<Dlgs.h>` are in use. They are the symbolic constants for control ID's used in the common dialogs (like the Open File Dialog). If you want to customize a common dialog you will need those ID's (see [Explorer-Style Hook Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Hook_Procedures)). Plus, assigning a different ID to every control in every dialog is indeed not possible. Control ID's are limited to 16 bits.

Comment: lovely ... Now we are also restricted in using some variable names by the compiler :)

Comment: @fritzone: No, by some header. That's fairly usual, though.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have already had a variable called lst, which has a type of int.
yes, i agree it looks like a bug of the compiler, since you are in a new variable space with if(secondStep){} wrapped.